# What is the sequence of execution for platform events in salesforce?

Tags: platform-event

If two platform events are published at same time, which one fires first? Can we control which platform event has to fire first ?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? Please edit your post, do not reply in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can understand this behavior from below line from [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_apex.htm#:%7E:text=Unlike%20triggers%20on%20standard%20or,the%20trigger%20processes%20the%20event.):-

An Apex trigger processes platform event notifications sequentially in the order they’re received. The order of events is based on the event replay ID. An Apex trigger can receive a batch of events at once. The maximum batch size in a platform event trigger is 2,000 event messages. The order of events is preserved within each batch. The events in a batch can originate from one or more publishers.

Unlike triggers on standard or custom objects, triggers on platform events don’t execute in the same Apex transaction as the one that published the event. The trigger runs asynchronously in its own process. As a result, there can be a delay between when an event is published and when the trigger processes the event.